# how to show a youtube video into WP7 application?

Tags: windows-phone-7, youtube

I want to develop a WP7 application. In this one, I would like to get video from youtube. For example, videos of a channel.
So, I know, I need youtube API, but I don't find a simple example to subscribe a channel and receive the latest video...

Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance , have a nice day !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to play Youtube video in a wp7 app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869564/possible-to-play-youtube-video-in-a-wp7-app)

Comment: Hello Filburt, it"s not the same question, I want to subscribe to a channel directly from my app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there are simple RSS feeds for each channel... If there are no RSS feeds, parse the HTML feed (e.g. http://www.youtube.com/user/nokia/feed)

To play youtube videos, see
http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=YouTube

Comment: Thank you Rico, I will check that

Answer (score 1):

WP7 currently doesn't have a standard media layer for YouTube videos and you need the YouTube app in order to be able to play those. Unless you want to work on a low level with the encoding format used by YouTube, but then again - you would have to implement a decoding service.

To play a youtube Video you need to use the WebBrowserTask and open the target URL in the browser; if the youtube app is installed, it will play, if not installed, it will prompt the user to install and then play.

How to subscribe ?

I don't think if it's possible to make that directly from your app...

Comment: Thank you for your response Francesco, I will check that