# Stream YouTube videos in a Windows Phone app

Tags: windows-phone-7

How do I stream YouTube videos in a Windows Phone app? I've tried using the MediaElement control and setting its Source property with the URL to a video and called the Play() method on the media element, but it didn't work. I want to create a simple video player that plays a video as it is being streamed. What kind of .NET classes do I need to work with?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to play Youtube video in a wp7 app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869564/possible-to-play-youtube-video-in-a-wp7-app)

Answer (score 0):

YouTube does not expose its videos in a format which you can use to play them within Windows Phone applications, or any other kind of application for that matter. This is why services such as [KeepVid](http://keepvid.com/), which provide 'hacks' for downloading YouTube videos, exist.

Comment: There is a youtube app for WP .. how that is able to play youtube videos in Windows Phone ? Isn't there a way like rtsp streaming ?

Comment: The YouTube app is basically a web page.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer to this identical question from a few months ago over @ [Possible to play Youtube video in a wp7 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869564/possible-to-play-youtube-video-in-a-wp7-app/4879138#4879138)