# youtube metadata on windows phone

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, windows-phone-8

I am planning to develop an app for the windows phone.

In this app actually, I need some metadata from youtube for each user, especially the videos they like and their playlists on youtube.
But, as I started to google for it, I came across this news that youtube apis are not fully supported on windows phone.

```
http://www.infoworld.com/t/windows-phone/in-blocking-windows-phone-access-youtube-google-delivers-rough-justice-210116
```

So, I wanted to know whether this feature can be implemented in windows phone app or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GData APIs work just fine on WP7/WP8 AFAIK. IANAL but it works fine and I haven't seen any official disclaimer saying it won't/shouldn't work. I believe this article has more to do about streaming video APIs then GData APIs.

You can see a sample of those APIs and how to use them in [the official docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#formatsp) and in this previous answer of mine @ [Possible to play Youtube video in a wp7 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869564/possible-to-play-youtube-video-in-a-wp7-app/4879138#4879138)

Comment: so i can get all the data I want..right?
[user's likes and their playlists]

Comment: AFAIK, yes. This isn't legal advice though.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user metadata using YouTube Data API v3.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists

from the documentation:

> YouTube also uses playlists to identify special collections of videos
>   for a channel, such as:
>
> - uploaded videos
> - favorite videos
> - positively rated (liked) videos
> - watch history
> - watch later

The API can be consumed from any client, if you use any JSON library and OAUTH2 authentication.

This project shows how to do it;

https://yt-topic-explorer.googlecode.com/git/dist/index.html