# Why does MediaElement show nothing?

Tags: windows-phone-7, video, windows-phone-7.1, mediaelement

I tried different ways, but whatever I set to `Source` of `MediaElement` it shows nothing.

I try this way:

```
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="White">
        <MediaElement x:Name="VideoMediElement" Source="{Binding VideoUrl, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="350" Height="340" Margin="55,33,75,225"></MediaElement>
    </Grid>
```

I try this:

```
VideoMediElement.Source = new Uri(VideoUrl);
VideoMediElement.Play();
```

where `VideoUrl` is:

```
 private string videoUrl;
    public string VideoUrl
    {
        get { return videoUrl; }
        set
        {
            if (videoUrl != value)
            {
                videoUrl = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("VideoUrl");
            }
        }
    }
```

I even try this:

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="White">
        <MediaElement x:Name="VideoMediElement" Source="http://www.youtube.com/v/zsGczPb-4fg?f=videos" Width="350" Height="340" Margin="55,33,75,225"></MediaElement>
```

But anywhere I see only white background. Why?
I use emulator version 7.1 .

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272293/youtube-on-windows-phone-with-mediaelement

Comment: @Xin  But I want to play not only youtube videos.

Comment: Have you tried playing it on a device? Maybe the emulator doesn't support the codec.

Comment: @keyboardP I have no device yet, and I don't think it is codec problem. I show it by webbrowsertask instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well did you tried subscribing to event [MediaFailed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.mediafailed%28VS.95%29.aspx)? Maybe something is going wrong with your video and this event may help you find out what.

Also try your application on device. However you cannot play media when you are connected to device via Zune. You have to use [WPConnect](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2010/11/03/tips-for-debugging-wp7-media-apps-with-wpconnect.aspx). It will allow you to connect to phone without Zune and play media in application.

Comment: Thanks, I solve this problem with another way, I just show it by WEbBrowserTask

Comment: I just saw that you are using URL from YouTube, so it won't work in your application. You are right using WebBrowserTask. This is the fastest way to get YouTube working from your application.

Comment: @ Damian Antonowicz Ok thanks, so I the best way to show youtube video's is WebBrowserTask ?